# Node.js mqtt ssl script

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I made a script to connect my linux CentOS VM as a client to my mosquitto MQTT broker.  Just trying to connect at the moment using SSL.  To publish and subscribe the broker requires username and password.  But when I run the script using:

`node websitemqttclient.js`

I am just getting the message below, and the cursor sits in a blank space for approx 1.5 minutes before execution is finished and a new command can be entered.  I see the depreciation notice but it doesn't appear to be a problem yet.  Also I have verified the 8883 port is open on the broker and its set-up so I believe the issue is with the client and its code.

```
user [bin]# node websitemqttclient.js
(node:30037) [DEP0123] DeprecationWarning: Setting the TLS ServerName to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066. This will be ignored in a future version.
connected  false
```

Is my script actually connecting to my broker or is it just sitting in the loop without connecting to the broker?

Main Code:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//setup
var mqtt    = require('mqtt'); //for client use
const fs = require('fs');
var count =0; //connected to an end script function
var caFile = fs.readFileSync("/pathway/bin/ca.crt");

var options={
host:'brokerip',
port:8883,
clientId:"yo",
username:"user",
password:"password",
protocol: 'mqtts',
clean:true,
rejectUnauthorized: false,
retain:false, 
ca:caFile 
}

var client  = mqtt.connect(options);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//connection dialog

//handle incoming messages
client.on('message',function(topic, message, packet){
    console.log("message is "+ message);
    console.log("topic is "+ topic);
});
client.on("connect",function(){ 
console.log("connected  "+ client.connected);
})
//handle errors
client.on("error",function(error){
console.log("Can't connect" + error);
process.exit(1)});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

count+=1;  //quit script after the execution of two loops
if (count==2) //ens script
    clearTimeout(timer_id); //stop timer
    client.end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.connected` won't return `true` until after the on `connect` event handler has been completed.

Add a call to `client.subscribe()` to the on `connect` event handler so you actually have some messages to trigger the on `message` event handler

Comment: I believe you are mentioning this portion: client.on("connect",function(){ 
console.log("connected  "+ client.connected); but I am a somewhat new to this so I am not sure how to add a call to the client.subscribe.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Without calling the subscribe function then the broker will never send any messages to client so it will just sit there waiting for messages that will never arrive. See the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#user-content-mqttclientsubscribetopictopic-arraytopic-object-options-callback)

Comment: So is the client actually reaching the broker?  Or do I need to use the subscribe function from the broker to confirm this.

Comment: If on `connect` was called the client is connected, but you won't get any messages until you subscribe to a topic